# seperate css ref for mobile, recommended max device width?

Tags: css, mobile, responsive

Figured out how to make separate css, to use in cases of mobile use, which is cool. works like this:

```
<link href="mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen        
and (max-device-width: 480px)" />
```

Is this a safe number to set the pixels at for most general smart phones like the iphone and galaxy? I don't want to have multiple mobile ref, just one that will cover them all for the most part. Is the above code basically saying, anything below pixel width of 480, will go to that css ref?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

No, this not fully safe in terms of serving to all devices.  Ideally, you want responsive design to also deal with tablets, not just smartphones, tablet users often do not have access to a mouse.  The most common tablet resolution is 768x1024 (for me this is about 75% of tablet traffic, over 6% of my web traffic in total, and there are also some larger phones in there) and there are a few oddball smartphones (making up about 1-2% of total traffic) in the 500-600 resolution range.

In general, I recommend using max-width and not max-device-width, because it makes the site collapse to a mobile format when in a small window on desktop, which is ultimately more useful to the user.

In my opinion, best practice is not to use a separate mobile stylesheet but rather use CSS media queries to make the elements of your webdesign responsive, which you can do within a single stylesheet.  You can then have some elements collapse into a single-column layout at certain widths, and others at other widths, again using max-width but using it on individual elements.

This allows you to make the best of the intermediate widths.  Some two-column layouts or horizontal menus, will look fine on a tablet, others you will need to collapse to a single column or a hidden vertical mobile menu.  Fidget with the widths for each element and you'll get a flexible design that works optimally on all devices.

This way you don't try to guess the device type, just redesign element by element based on the window width.  You can do away with "only screen" too.